How can I automatically fill remaining space in a Bootstrap 2 progress bar?
I have a Bootstrap progress bar. I’d like the last div, which has the classes bar bar-warning to occupy everything that isn’t already occupied by the other inner divs without me having to do calculations. i’d like to get something like width: everything-else, however obviously that isn’t valid css. i’ve tried different solutions, such as making the width auto, 100%, -100% etc, but none of these work sadly.
An alternative solution would be to just put the text into that area and center it relative to the non-filled area. However, I couldn’t do that either.


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" integrity="sha512-Fik9pU5hBUfoYn2t6ApwzFypxHnCXco3i5u+xgHcBw7WFm0LI8umZ4dcZ7XYj9b9AXCQbll9Xre4dpzKh4nvAQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<div class="progress progress-striped">
  <div class="bar bar-success" style="width: 14.5%;"></div>
  <div class="bar bar-info" style="width: 14.6%;"></div>
  <div class="bar bar-warning" style="width: 70.9%;"></div>
</div>




Are you really still using Bootstrap version 2? In more current versions, that are flexbox based, this would probably be easier.

Bootstrap 2 reached end of life 11 years ago. Not only that, it's badly out of date from a best practices standpoint. You really need to upgrade your site.

You can use flex for this:


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" integrity="sha512-Fik9pU5hBUfoYn2t6ApwzFypxHnCXco3i5u+xgHcBw7WFm0LI8umZ4dcZ7XYj9b9AXCQbll9Xre4dpzKh4nvAQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<div class="progress progress-striped" style="display: flex;">
  <div class="bar bar-success" style="width: 14.5%;"></div>
  <div class="bar bar-info" style="width: 14.6%;"></div>
  <div class="bar bar-warning" style="flex-grow:1;"></div>
</div>




For a no-CSS solution, just put the warning bar styles on the chart itself, so they show wherever other bars don't.
We can hack the markup a bit to take advantage of Bootstrap's style classes. By moving the controlling class out a level we maintain the ancestral relationship necessary to do so. This eliminates the need for a final bar, but if you do have one it doesn't have a width anyway, so it's not a problem.


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" integrity="sha512-Fik9pU5hBUfoYn2t6ApwzFypxHnCXco3i5u+xgHcBw7WFm0LI8umZ4dcZ7XYj9b9AXCQbll9Xre4dpzKh4nvAQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<div class="progress-striped">
  <div class="progress bar bar-warning">
    <div class="bar bar-success" style="width: 14.5%;"></div>
    <div class="bar bar-info" style="width: 44.6%;"></div>
    <div class="bar bar-warning"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="progress bar bar-warning">
    <div class="bar bar-success" style="width: 54.5%;"></div>
    <div class="bar bar-info" style="width: 24.6%;"></div>
  </div>
</div>



If you actually need the final bar to be present and the proper size, you can use flexbox.


.progress {
  display: flex;
}

.progress .bar:last-child {
  flex: auto;
}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" integrity="sha512-Fik9pU5hBUfoYn2t6ApwzFypxHnCXco3i5u+xgHcBw7WFm0LI8umZ4dcZ7XYj9b9AXCQbll9Xre4dpzKh4nvAQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<div class="progress progress-striped">
  <div class="bar bar-success" style="width: 14.5%;"></div>
  <div class="bar bar-info" style="width: 44.6%;"></div>
  <div class="bar bar-warning"></div>
</div>

<div class="progress progress-striped">
  <div class="bar bar-success" style="width: 34.5%;"></div>
  <div class="bar bar-info" style="width: 14.6%;"></div>
  <div class="bar bar-warning"></div>
</div>



